# Chrome extension to save all downloaded media for the current page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, snapshot, save-as

I know of winhttrack but it doesn't go well with javascript.

Is there a Google extension that will save all the ressources that have been downloaded since you're visiting a site in a tab ?
(all the files that you can see in developper mode/sources and that you can save as but one by one only)

Ctrl+S saves nothing usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I've never been able to find a good Chrome extension capable of doing that; However, there is a Firefox exttension if you are willing to install Firefox for specific uses like that. DownThemAll! (dTa) is one of the best advanced download managers I've ever used. Might just give it a look and see if it will suffice.

http://www.downthemall.net/

Regards,

Chris